# How do I read data from Google Sheets tab produced by BigQuery Data Connector?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api

We have a system that reads the values from the user's Google Sheets tab. The user selects the tab from which the data will be extracted. This process is working fine for ordinary tabs, but it's failing to read data from tabs that are Data Connector for BigQuery.

The Sheets API returns a HTTP 400 error stating that the range is not valid.

```
Details: Unable to parse range: Teams!A1:C10
```

I've looked into the Google Sheets API reference but could not find any example on how to get the values from a Sheets tab connected to BigQuery. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Connected Sheets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets) to share BigQuery data from your Google Sheets spreadsheet. Note though from the official docs, "because VPC Service Controls does not support Sheets, you might not be able to access BigQuery data that VPC Service Controls is protecting." You can go over the documentations [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connected-sheets#vpc-service-controls), [configuring ingress and egress policies](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/configuring-ingress-egress-policies), and [configuring access levels](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/use-access-levels).